# Node Transparent Material Not Working

Tags: node-editor

So I set up a mix shader node and added a transparent bdsf node to it and am trying to change the blend of it to alpha blend but the property tag isn't showing my blend settings.[image]

Comment: What engine are you using Eevee or Cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to the *Options* tab to see the *Blend Mode* setting.

[image: Options tab]